# What do the Swirling Circles behind my character mean?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

Occasionally, on some levels I noticed a circle appearing behind my character at what seems like random intervals:

[image: circle]

They seem to be randomly colored each time too.

What do these circles mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These circles indicate that you've reached a checkpoint on the map.  Should you fall off the platforms to the slime below, you will respawn on the platform where you last saw one of these circles appear.

Note that you should only see these circles appear on "Race" game mode maps.